# authentication with google it does not work it redirect to 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, google-authentication

i want to login with `gmail`, i create laravel authentication, i add button login with google, i install laravel socialite package by command `composer require laravel/socialite`, i add configuration in `config/services:`

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/laravel-socialite/public/login/google/callback',
    ],
```

I added in `routes/web.php` the routes:

```
Route::get ('login/google',[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'redirectToGoogle'])->name('login.google');
Route::get('login/google/callback',[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'handleGoogleCallback']);
```

I put in the button "login with google" url:

```
<a href="{{ route('login.google') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">login with Google</a>
```

I put id and variable key in the `.env` file:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="759714452408-gcbbdff9d7tp6215vgla9qhvrf60juh8.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="ZKgJSqgibBNcHzD9vAMB80cw"
```

I created the `_registerOrLoginUser` function in `loginController`:

```
protected function _registerOrLoginUser ($ data)
    {
        $ user = User :: where ('email', '=', $ data-> email) -> first ();
        if (! $ user) {
            $ user = new User ();
            $ user-> name = $ data-> name;
            $ user-> email = $ data-> email;
            $ user-> provider_id = $ data-> provider_id;
            $ user-> avatar = $ data-> avatar;
            $ user-> save ();
        }
        Auth :: login ($ user);
    }
```

I added the two function in `LoginController.php` and called the `_registerOrLoginUser` function and redirect to "`home`".

```
 public function redirectToGoogle () {
            return Socialite :: driver ('google') -> redirect ();
        }
        public function handleGoogleCallback () {
            $ user = Socialite :: driver ('google') -> user ();
            $ this -> _ registerOrLoginUser ($ user);
            return redirect () -> route ('home');
        }
```

I created google application to get id and sercret.

`database/table` users migrations:

```
public function up ()
    {
        Schema :: create ('users', function (Blueprint $ table) {
            $ table-> id ();
            $ table-> string ('name');
            $ table-> string ('email');
            $ table-> timestamp ('email_verified_at') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> string ('password');
            $ table-> string ('provider_id') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> string ('avatar') -> nullable ();
            $ table-> rememberToken ();
            $ table-> timestamps ();
        });
    }
```

and finally when I click on the button "login with google" it opens `gmail` and I choose my account, it redirects to `404 NOT FOUND` whose link:

```
http://localhost:8000/laravel-socialite/public/login/google/callback?state=zeKKpMpBltK1KYyaqiCM55ii0FjNj6KN03e23eiN&code=4%2F0AX4XfWj3m2DoJOXwolKO0ANQOa8CMW8fCx_5ASs1eYT5_NNqDFO0m_5Fn6OIOmyA0o2Rcg&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent#
```

Comment: Not sure if this is caught by Laravel or your browser, but have you tried removing the space from `'http://localhost: 8000/...`?

Comment: Also, is `http://localhost:8000/laravel-socialite/public` your project root? The `public` folder should not appear in the URL

Comment: Security note: if you x out your `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` and `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` from your `.env` file you should also x them in the 404 url you posted. Better delete this question and post it again with any secrets x'ed out

Comment: @brombeer thx for u answer , i try to remove public but not work,

Answer (score 0):

You see the method `handleGoogleCallback()` that means that google server need to be able to contact directly your server.

You should know that a link like `http://localhost:8000` will not be reachable from the exterior of your own computer.

To make it work, you need to do some fiddling with your router and use your external IP as the server domain

or

use a NOIP solution to get a temporary reachable domain. (with still some fiddling to open needed ports).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this `http://localhost:8000` and use proper domain name you shoud first live your site then you can make authentication of google .